# Page break in float pages

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I have an appendix section with half a page of text followed by a lot of tables. I want all these tables to go on float pages for the nice distribution on the pages, so placement specified as [p]. First there are five tables of same size belonging together, two of them fitting on a page. Next there are two tables belonging together and fitting on a page together. Then again two tables belonging together and fitting on a page together.
Problem is if I just let Latex do what it does, it puts the first two tables on a page, then the next two on a second page, but then the last one of the first five and the first of the first group of two on a page, so exactly not putting the tables together that belong together.

What I want is to tell Latex to let the fifth table be alone on a its float page and continuing with the rest on the next page.

I tried \clearpage, \pagebreak, \newpage and even \FloatBarrier.
\clearpage and \FloatBarrier do what I want but with the ugly side effect of inserting a whole blank page. This blank page is probably a normal page followed by the float pages. Problem is I have no text or other stuff to fill that blank page so it stays blank and is completely unnecessary.

Is there a way to solve this? How can I suppress the creation of the non-float-page blank page? How can I control the placement of the floats on the float pages in such a case where text between the floats is completely absent? Can I group floats to specify which should be put together? Can I mimic the float placement of float pages on normal pages? Can I define invisible floats that act as space in float pages to control which floats are placed on a page together?

Comment: `\clearpage` after your text and then after the fifth float should do what you ask (it shouldn't force a blank page, if it does please try to generate an example)

Comment: Thanks. It works, I just realized it actually works with just the \clearpage after the fifth float. But my case is actually more complicated: I also have two code listings with lstlisting environment configured as floats at the end, and now I moved them to after the fifth float. They seem to be the cause of the blank page. What does lstlisting differently than normal floats that could trigger this behavior?
I'm not sure how to add an example.

Comment: I'm confused, the package is called "listings" and the environment is called "lstlisting". The resulting listing isn't a float unless you set the option called "float", then it should be a float.

Comment: sorry I wrote nonsense (deleted the comment) so back to ususal request to add an example that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\clearpage` after your first group of tables (it should not make a blank page) or just make the last of the first group bigger so the second group has to start on a new page for example

```
\begin{table}[p]
\begin{tabular}...
\caption{...}
\vspace{.4\textheight}
\end{table}
```